Reference for a Fibonacci identity with binomial coefficients and powers of 5
Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers $$f_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^i-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^i\right)
$$ is a bit odd because it includes radicals in its formulation, even though the Fibonacci numbers themselves are integers. You can bypass this oddity by expanding the powers with the binomial theorem and cancelling like terms, resulting in a sum involving powers of five and binomial coefficients with odd lower indices  $$f_i=\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{i-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{i}{2j+1}5^j .$$
Surely, this formula must have been figured out hundreds of years ago. However, I cannot find a reference. Can someone provide one?

A reference is art of problem solving.

Those questions are similar for sure. I was just looking for a reference. Many thanks.

The reference is: Vajda-91, B&Q(2003)-Identity 235, and Catalan 1857, see here. So it goes back indeed to Catalan.

Wow, it only goes back 167 years, much less than I expected! That's all I needed. Many thanks!

Note that there is a tag "math-history" and a specialized HSM site (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) for requests regarding historical results. Many hsm specialists also monitor this math-history tag here.

The formula goes back to Catalan in 1857, see this site.
But note that there is an easier formula in terms of a binomial sum. We have
$$ F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}\binom{n-1-k}k
  \qquad\text{for }n\geq1.
$$
The other formula is often used for divisibility by $5$ questions, and also for proving that $p$ divides the Fibonacci number $F_{p^2-1}$, for a prime $p\neq 5$.
